# Selecting unique data after removing white space

Tags: php, mysql, removing-whitespace

I have the following MySQL statement:

```
SELECT registration FROM
  (SELECT registration FROM installs
      WHERE customer_id = :id1
  UNION SELECT registration FROM services
      WHERE customer_id = :id2
  UNION SELECT registration FROM deinstalls
      WHERE customer_id = :id3)
AS vehicles
```

I need to select unique "registration"'s from multiple tables which this statement does almost perfectly.

It selects `AB01 CDE` and `aB01 cdE` as one item, however `AB01CDE` / `aB01cdE` are selected as a different item.

I have tried using `REPLACE` around the first `registration` to remove spaces when selecting unique items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`REPLACE()` should work.  Did you do this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT REPLACE(registration, ' ', '') as Registration
FROM (SELECT registration
      FROM installs
      WHERE customer_id = :id1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT registration
      FROM services
      WHERE customer_id = :id2
      SELECT registration
      FROM deinstalls
      WHERE customer_id = :id3
     ) v;
```

It is also possible that the separating characters are not spaces, in which case this will not work.

Comment: Works perfectly but just out of curiosity what does the "v" at the end do?

Comment: @robbo5899 . . . The `v` is a table alias.  MySQL requires table aliases for subqueries in the `from` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I think this maybe what you are looking for?

```
SELECT registration FROM customers WHERE customer_id in
  (SELECT registration AS installs_registration FROM installs WHERE customers.customer_id = installs.id,
  SELECT registration AS services_registration FROM services  WHERE customers.customer_id = services.id,
  SELECT registration AS deinstalls_registration FROM deinstalls WHERE customers.customer_id = deinstalls.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. The first is to add `DISTINCT` to the first `REPLACE` on `registration`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT REPLACE(registration, ' ', '') FROM (
  ... your UNION queries
)
AS vehicles
```

The second is to use `REPLACE` in each of your subqueries; the `UNION` ensures that you'll get distinct results:

```
SELECT registration FROM (
  SELECT REPLACE(registration, ' ', '') AS registration
    FROM installs
    WHERE customer_id = :id1
  UNION SELECT REPLACE(registration, ' ', '')
    FROM services
    WHERE customer_id = :id2
  UNION SELECT REPLACE(registration, ' ', '')
    FROM deinstalls
   WHERE customer_id = :id3
)
AS vehicles
```